# Animate border-style

Tags: javascript, css, svg

There is a way to animate through border-styles?

Using SCSS:

```
.check {
    ...
    transition: border-style .2s linear;
    border-style: dashed;
    &.opened {
        border-style: solid;
    }
}
```

This way, the dashed canvas would be filled to become solid. But, obviously, the code above don't work.
There is a way of doing this, it could be with JS, svg, or any approach. Any idea?

### Fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/2p4hnvve/

Comment: I think you are not clear about your requirement . please explain what exactly you want ?

Comment: From the very first line: "There is a way to **animate** through border-styles?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since some browsers are unable to animate the `border-style` property, this could also be done with SVG like follows.

First, we create a box as inline-svg:

```
<svg class="box" width="400" height="300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300"/>
</svg>
```

Then we style it with CSS and give it a uniformly dashed border with the `stroke-dasharray` property. On hover, we animate that property so that each dash takes up the space of the gap additionally and the gaps take up 0%:

```
.box rect {
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 1em;
    stroke-dasharray: 10% 10%;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 0.2s linear;
}

.box:hover rect {
    stroke-dasharray: 20% 0%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5bc06op/3/

```css
.box rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 0.25em;
  stroke-dasharray: 6% 6%;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 0.2s ease;
}

.box:hover rect {
  stroke-dasharray: 12% 0%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="box" width="120" height="90"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="120" height="90"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Now we're talking! Thank you, mr.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my previous little comment, I made a JS Fiddle for you.
Looks working, if you use another html element:

```
<div class="round">
   <div class="round_bis"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KCarnaille/d4mezrmk/

Comment: Nice alternate solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a `<div>` inside that element in `position:absolute` then playing with `box-shadow` cause it accepts transition.

Take a look to the following workaround:

```css
.check {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px transparent;
}
.check > div {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #ccc;
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
}

.check:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #ccc;
}

.check:hover > div {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="check"><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
transition: all 0.2s;
```

Comment: What would be the difference between setting a transition value from 'border-style' property to 'all' properties? Nevertheless, i tested and it doesn't work.

Comment: I've veryfied on my side, and I don't think you can apply a border-style transition. Only for border-color or border-width.
What you can test is applying a border on that div (like 1px solid red) and play with a children border, you know what I mean ?
When hovering the div, parent border style fade out, and children fade In (play only with the color, from transparent to the one you want)